# Is there any difference between chakki and stoneground whole wheat flour?

Tags: indian-cuisine, wholewheat

Many websites have been telling that stoneground white whole wheat flour outside India yields lofty breads but 'CHAKKI MILLED' white whole wheat flour gives dense and crumbly breads. Take a look

[image: Chakki milled flour]
This is made from chakki milled white whole wheat

[image: h]

made from KA whole wheat flour(i do not know whether roller mill or stoneground)

Chakki and stonegrounding device look same to me so I dont understand why there is a difference in the flour therefore in the loaf too.

[image]

This is a traditional chakki. These days chakkis are modernised with an electric motor.

Comment: Your question says "'CHAKKI MILLED' whole wheat flour(white)".  Which is it? Whole wheat or white?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but i'm referring to white whole wheat flour not the traditional wholewheat flour in America (both are whole wheat) but it shouldn't matter as white wholewheat flour yields more light breads

Comment: "White whole-wheat flour is flour milled from hard white spring wheat, rather than traditional red wheat. In the United Kingdom and India, whole-wheat flour is more commonly made from white wheat instead of red as in the United States"...................Wikipedia

Comment: I'm British, so (for me) there's no need to describe the wheat as white. Those more familiar with the distinction may disagree but if you need to specify I'd say "from white wheat" rather than using "white" to refer to the resulting flour.

Comment: You mention expecting "lofty" bread, bread that's risen tall.  With the two loaves you have pictured, a freeform loaf will always be shorter and more spread out than the pan-baked loaf - the pan sides give the loaf structure to allow it to rise high instead of slump sideways.  This doesn't answer the dense&crumbly attributes, or the differences in flour, but it will make a difference in height if that's one of the things you're looking for.

Comment: Also there may be other differences between commercially produced loaves which favor consistency and height and soft texture, and artisan-style or rustic loaves which often are looking for different attributes (flavor, texture, sturdiness) and may favor attributes that would be flaws in mass-produced loaves.  It may be more difficult to compare these different kinds of loaves to each other.